# Variable too long

Tags: stata

Some of my variables are too long, so either they are cut off or if I increase my variable width then the table can't fit.

One possible solution is that the variable continues on the second line.

How should I do that?

My code:

```
estout m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8, cells(b(fmt(2)) se(par fmt(2))) legend label drop(`drop' _cons) stats(r2 N, label(R-squared Number of observations)) numbers mgroups("Dependent variable is log GDP per capita in 1995" "Dependent variable is log output per worker in 1988", pattern(1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0)) title("TABLE 2—OLS REGRESSIONS")
```

Example attached:

[image]

My goal is to replicate this table:

[image]

Comment: What command are you using? It's hard to answer your question without knowing that. In any case I don't think any author is likely to code such an option into the program. If you did this with `esttab` or `estout` you can experiment with the `onecell` option, which may solve your problem if you export the table.

Comment: Variables too long could mean (1) values of string variable too long to show comfortably (2) value labels ditto (3) variable labels ditto (4) something else. Please clarify.

Comment: @NickCox it is (3)

Comment: @Wouter edited the question. added the code. thanks

Comment: What is the goal here? Even if it is something else than Stata output, it will still have finite limits on what you can show in the space available, e.g. on a printed page. If you were my Ph.D. student I would just emphasise the non-Stata point of being more concise. For example, "dependent variable" could be replaced by "outcome" or "response" and the word "dummy" is dispensable.

Comment: @NickCox attached my goal. I understand your point. But I was wondering if the publication could do it, why can't we? Which other software do they use?

Comment: Your concerns are practical but SO needs a focused and soluble question and there is nothing reproducible here. We don't have your dataset and can't run your code to play. Sorry, but I have no certainty what software was used to produce a table in a publication I didn't write or don't edit, but LaTeX is one answer.. What is possible in `estout` is documented in detail and for what it can do the help is the source. Otherwise the (not helpful, but still pertinent) answer on this forum, which is for programmers, is that you may need to write your own program.

Comment: @11111111111 I have read this paper and it is clear that the authors have used Stata for their regressions, but it is not certain that the authors used Stata entirely to create the final table. They might have made some last aesthetic changes in their document preparation software, perhaps LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You can hard code the model titles with an option that looks like this:

```
mtitles("A" "\shortstack{B\\C}" "D")
```

Comment: Yes, it is just an option, goes after the comma in estout.

Comment: Also, it is Stata, not STATA.